# gui.ava.html.Html2Image not rendering text-overflow

Tags: java, html

I am trying to convert a dynamically generated HTML to Image using gui.ava.html.Html2Image class. I get the image but I see that certain properties like "text-overflow:ellipsis;" and "box-sizing: border-box;" is not understood while converting to image. The HTML I generate is fine on all browsers. But Html2Image ignores those properties.

The HTML (test.html) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.a {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.a:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The text-overflow Property</h1>

<p>Hover over the div below, to see the entire text.</p>

<div class="a">This is some long text that will not fit in the box.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code snippet is:

```
Html2Image generator = Html2Image.fromFile(new File("test.html"));
final ImageRenderer imageRenderer = generator.getImageRenderer();
imageRenderer.saveImage(new File("test.png"));
```